# Dynamic download of .xap file in SIlverlight MEF

Tags: silverlight

I have three siverlight projects P1,P2 and P3. I am using package catalog in all the projects.

For example, in P1 I am using MEF to download P2 and P3 and I did same thing in other two projects. When I run P1, P2 and P3 are downloaded and when I use P2 P1 and P3 are downloaded as specified in the package catalog.

I want to avoid the duplicate downloads for the projects. Is it possible to prevent the download of P1 ,P2 and P3 each time? Are there any attributes I can set for the project / catalog to this effect?